# Can't enable ssh for first boot because latest Raspbian image boot partition is read only

Tags: ssh, raspbian-stretch, setup, headless

I'm trying to set up my Raspberry Pi headless from my MacBook. However, when I flash the latest Raspian image (April 2018 version), the resulting `boot` partition has a read-only file system. I've tried using both Etcher and the `dd` utility, specifically

`$ dd bs=1m if=2018-04-18-raspbian-stretch.img of=/dev/disk2`

In both cases, I end up with an SD card like this:

`$ diskutil list
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *32.0 GB    disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 boot                    45.2 MB    disk2s1
   2:                      Linux                         32.0 GB    disk2s2`

I now want to mount the drive and put the empty `ssh` file in the boot directory. However, no matter what I try, I cannot modify anything on the boot directory:

`$ sudo touch /Volumes/boot/ssh
touch: /Volumes/boot/ssh: Read-only file system
exit 1`

Because of this I'm not able to ssh in and do my initial setup. I've just checked and it's the same story with the Raspbian Lite image. What am I missing?

Comment: mount it read/write? `sudo mount /Volumes/boot -o remount,rw`

Comment: @JaromandaX, that worked! Turned out to be a bit of a different command on my system but `sudo mount -uw /Volumes/boot` did the trick. I wasn't aware of remounting, thanks!

Comment: @johnpaton that command gives me `mount_msdos: /dev/disk3s6 on /Volumes/boot: Permission denied`

Comment: @philshem did you use `sudo`?

Comment: yes (but in the meantime I've hooked up a monitor and enabled ssh that way)